# Выравнивание элемента

Tags: html, css

Стоит задача: выровнять надпись в блоке не ровно по центру, например чтобы она отставала от левого края блока на `60%`.

Соответственно нужно чтобы была адаптивность.

Сначала хотел сделать с `position: absolute`. Но во первых почти весь макет построен не по стандартной сетке и не хочется писать каждому блоку `position`, а во вторых нужно чтобы элементы не выпадали из потока.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Добавьте ваш код!

Comment: Вировнять текст по центру, и задать ему паддинг